# Firefox opens blank page instead of application url – Codeception and selenium2

Tags: php, macos, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I'm trying to use codeception for acceptance tests. I decided to use it with Selenium2.
Starting environment:

acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - Selenium2
        - WebHelper
    config:
          Selenium2:
              url: 'http://nemo.dev'
              browser: firefox
              delay: 1000
```

test:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('see text');
$I->amGoingTo('/');
$I->see('text');
```

After build and run Firefox starts, shows blank page, and exits.

In console:

```
1) Couldn't see text in SigninCept.php
Guy couldn't see "text": 'text' in .
Failed asserting that response contains "text". Response was saved to 'log' directory.

Scenario Steps:
2. I see "text"
1. I am going to /

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Running Mac OS X 10.8.3, selenium: selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar, PHP 5.3.15.
Failure, white screen screenshot in logs, no understanding of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty basic issue. You should specify the starting page. Always.
Insert this line before commands.

```
$I->amOnPage('/');
```

Comment: Feeling myself an idiot. Thanks, but probably you should remark this on any FaQ page, or any manual.

Comment: This helped me, too. I had no idea I had to specify a starting page in the test -- thank you, Davert!
Also, this is my first day with Codeception, but I love it.